# Where to upload app icon on iTunes Connect for TestFlight?

Tags: ios, icons, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app to the App Store to prepare for TestFlight. 
I thought there was supposed to be a separate form or section in iTunes Connect where I can add the app icon - but I cannot find the spot.
Does Apple pick the app icon up from the app bundle resources? I have both app icon and launch screen in the Xcode app.

Comment: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdc42b26b8

Comment: https://medium.com/@dmathewwws/steps-to-put-your-app-on-testflight-and-then-the-ios-app-store-10a7996411b1

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to add App icon specifically for Flight test mode. simply add app icon in app  General App Information module and it will use for Flight test as well as for live Uploading.

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.3.3. For this version and earlier, we need to add the app icon ourselves inside of iTunes Connect. I just had to scroll down in the General Information tab to find the slot for it.